Mobile Connect Contacts from Canada not receiving texts
I have seen some cases recently where contacts from Canada are not receiving texts sent from SFMC.
A contact who was opted in stops receiving texts. Tries to opt back in by sending signup keyword but does not receive response for double opt-in process. This happens even after sending signup keyword multiple times.
I tried opting in the contact via application, but none of texts sent via short code are being delivered to the contact. Weird thing is, SFMC logs (data views) and UI shows the texts are being sent and delivered.
I have confirmed that the mobile number is correct, is not deactivated by carriers, neither the number is on held list and is opted in as per SMSSubscriptionLog data view.
To check with SFMC Support, we need minimum 5 contact facing the same issue in last 7 days and I have less than 5 people facing this issue.
Has anyone faced this issue before? Any suggestions on how to fix this?
